# Prediction using keras LSTM layers

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

I'm new to python in general and specfically to "keras (2)" library and i'm having difficulties creating a regression lstm model for the following problem:

I'm trying to optimize performance related to stock market. The training data is a 595 stocks with 179 features each and 3000 time samples each. In total 595x179x3000.
First, the data is processed by concatenating the 595 stocks together to form a database matrix of dimenssion 179x1785000 - 1785000 time samples for each of the 179 features.

The **fit is not completed** because of the **"initial_epoch"** field.
It seems that the program enters an infinant loop. If you have any suggestion about my current problem or any other future problem regarding my attempt to solve the problem please do tell.

The relevant code:

```
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential
import time
import scipy.io


# x is 1785000x179 matrix
# y is 1785000x1 training target vector with values in                              
# the interval [-1.5,1.5] 

# Model design
model = Sequential()

# First layer
model.add(LSTM(units = 20, batch_size = 5000, input_shape = (1785000,179), 
activation = 'relu', dropout = 0.2, return_sequences = True))


# Second layer
model.add(LSTM(units = 15, activation = 'relu', dropout = 0.1, 
return_sequences = True))

# Third layer
model.add(LSTM(units = 5, activation = 'relu', return_sequences = True))

# Fourth layer
model.add(Dense(output_dim = 179, activation = 'linear' ))

# Compilation
model.compile(loss = 'mse',optimizer = 'rmsprop')

# Training
model.fit(x, y, batch_size = 5000, epochs = 2, verbose = 1)


# Testing
# predicting the 1638 target values for the 595 stocks,  
# one 1x1638 vector at a time 
for k in range(595):
    x_test = (database['features'][k][3000:4638])
    y_test.append(model.predict(x_test))
```

Comment: "The fit is not completed because of the "initial_epoch" field." --- What do you mean?

Comment: Could you provide some sample output from running your code? I know you mention it reaches an infinite loop, try taking a screen shot when it reaches that point, or copying the terminal output if possible.

Comment: Also if I understand the data correctly.. I think you are using the LSTM/RNN inappropriately. You seem to be "collapsing" you're time dimension into you feature dimension. LSTMs/RNNs work on sequences of data, where in this case, the sequence is the time steps of the stock in question. Each sample should consist of 3000 time series (and time distributed) inputs of the shape 1x179 - with a total of 595 samples. During forward pass you would then provide a 1x179 feature vector which predicts the next feature vector of that stock.

Comment: Are you sure its an infinite loop and not just taking time to train? if you have 595 samples and a batch size of 5000, then its going to train on all samples (note not sure what happens when batchsize>samples...may be repeating data). and this will take some time considering your providing 179 timesteps and 3000 features. Try dropping the batch size in this example to say 10, bet it will start printing...also as @KDecker noted your setup is wrong. You should really understand network design, before you start throwing data at it...

Comment: Thank you all for the fast respone.
Apperantely, the dimenssions were wrong and i'm no longer experiencing the infinite loop.

I have another question:
I've redesigned the model so that it recieves 179 features sampled 3000 times and:
    # First layer
    model.add(LSTM(input_shape=(3000, 179), return_sequences=True, 
    units=32))

Now when i try to enter my test data which consists of 179 features sampled 1638 times and use predict, i  get dimenssion error and i don't know how to make it work.